# localhost is redirecting to 127.0.0.1 after submitting form in Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem in my code. I have a form in my code that looks like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('users/auth/login', array('class' => 'form floating-label')); ?>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" />
        <label for="username">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <p class="help-block"><a href="#">Forgotten?</a></p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('note'); ?>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-ink" type="submit">Login Account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Then after clicking the submit it redirect my `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

After submitting the form it redirects me to

```
http://127.0.0.1/teradasys/index.php/user/login
```

Here's my controller

```
public function index() {

       if($this->aauth->is_loggedin()) {

       } else {
            $data['page_header'] = 'Login Form';
            $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
       }

    }

    public function login() {

        $identifier = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        if ($this->aauth->login($identifier, $password, true)){
            return true;
        } else {
            $note = $this->aauth->get_errors_array();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('note', $note[0]);

            $data['page_header'] = 'Login Form';
            $this->load->view('users/login', $data);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Need to change `base_url` in `config.php`

Comment: In codeigniter 3 it is all ways best to set your base url `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';` In the old versions you could leave it blank and submit forms OK but in CI3 you may run into issue if you do not set your base_url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check your base url in application/config/config.php

and change it.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';
```

Comment: Yeah it works thanks but I am confused because in my other project I didn't set the base_url and it is working

Comment: @Jerielle you're welcome. this is the important thing if you use codeigniter, make sure you not forget this.

Comment: Ok so when I move my project in a live host I also need to change this?

Comment: @Yoshioka when you set your base url it is all ways good at end of it to have forward slash `/` and `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 oh i forget last slash, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3):

Please check your base url in application/config/config.php

change from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

No need to change anything after placing this .If u r using local or live host.